# Как правильно использовать функцию _n() для множественного числа в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день, есть такой темплейт:

```
<div class="counters-item white">
<i class="i-comment"></i>
<?php comments_number(' 0', '1', '%'); ?> 
<span class="hide-for-small-only">
<?php _e('комментариев', 'como'); ?>
</span>
</div>
```

Как правильно использовать функцию чтобы можно было к 0 значению написать комментариев к 1 комментарий ну и к % комментариев?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблемы с множественным числом чаще всего возникают из-за неправильной настройке самого Poedit. Множественные числа в gettext обрабатываются с помощью функци _n(), _nx(), и _n_noop(). Эти три функции в Poedit должны быть описаны функции для множественного числа, эта настройка берется из файла .pot, или задается вручную в настройке программы.

После этого при создании нового перевода, вам необходимо указать формы множественного числа. Для русского языка это магическая строка (не пугайтесь):

```
nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);
```

После этого в строках с множественном числом, Poedit (и другие интерфейсы) предложат вам не два поля для ввода единсвтенного и множественного числа, а три: 1 комментарий, 2 комментария, 25 комментариев.

А в самом PO-файле надо написать:

```
#: archive-faq.php:101
#, php-format
msgid "%d question"
msgid_plural "%d questions"
msgstr[0] "%d вопрос"
msgstr[1] "%d вопроса"
msgstr[2] "%d вопросов"
```

Тогда в шаблоне будет:

```
<?php 
echo esc_html( sprintf( _n( '%d question', '%d questions', 'Число вопросов', 'домен' ), 'Число вопросов' ) );
?>
```

Comment: На самом деле вопрос был в другом, как правильно настроить темплейт чтобы код сработал?
_n('0 комментариев','1 комментарий','% комментариев','como'); 
Так или нет?

Comment: Обновил ответ с примером

Comment: @Puvvl на самом деле вам дали очень толковый и внятный ответ, закрывающий всю проблему целиком, а не только ваш частный вопрос.